# Scala 2.8 and Lift status

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, lift

Whats the status of Lift working with Scala 2.8?

I'm finding fragments of conversations about it on the web. I've been trying tweaking the pom.xml but I'm getting errors from the Lift side of things.

Comment: As 2.8 is undergoing alpha releases right now, any answer to this question is soon to be obsolete. Please, check the mailing lists instead.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I've signed up to the mailing lists. This is a very time based question, I would nearly consider deleting it?

Comment: Scala 2.8 and Lift 2.0 have been now released. I wonder if they are compatible.

Comment: As an update to this question, Lift 2.1 now completely supports Scala 2.8.0.  When resolving dependencies, just add _2.8.0 to the artifact name to pull down the Scala 2.8 compatible binaries: e.g. lift-util_2.8.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main trunk of Lift (including all the binaries available from scala-tools.org) will NOT run on Scala 2.8 due to breaking changes.

However... There are two branches: 280_dev and 280_port available on github (at http://github.com/dpp/liftweb) if you're prepared to compile it yourself.

As projects can't even be guaranteed binary compatible between sucessive nightly builds of Scala 2.8.   You would well be advised to wait at least until a 2.8 beta is released, as I believe that lift will also release a corresponding binary at this time.

**UPDATE**

Lift 2.1 has Scala 2.8 support.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, yea it seems like a bad idea to be making the jump at this stage.

Comment: Alos, it seems that 2.8 is b0rken when it comes to lift, as lift appears to have exposed some rather nasty bugs in the 2.8 compiler as it is.  There's a whole conversation on the lift google group.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that David Pollak has lift working with the current *alpha* release of 2.8. It was posted to o[ne of the scala forums](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/199) (available on nabble) a few days ago. Scala 2.8 is still in flux though, so it's not a finished project...

[This post](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/3974), for example, is a month old and states:

> I've got Lift compiling under Scala 2.8.  Well, not all of Lift, but enough of Lift to run the examples program

Answer (score 1):

To keep things current Scala is to go to beta next week (the end of Jan 2010), as for Liftweb it's 2.0-M1.